# Set buefy <b-dropdown> element to full width

Tags: vue.js, buefy

How can I change the  item to fill the 100% width?

Can't found any option for this, 
and I can not apply css rules to the .dropdown-trigger element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example Pen: https://codepen.io/Qumez/pen/RwPWeRV

The `b-dropdown` component appears to be `div.dropdown -> div[role="button"] -> button`
So by giving the div and it's child div, and the grandchild button all a width of 100%, I was able to get the component to expand to the full width.

```html
<div class="dropdown-box">
  <b-dropdown aria-role="list">
    <button class="button is-primary" slot="trigger">
      <span>Click me!</span>
      <b-icon icon="menu-down"></b-icon>
    </button>

     <!-- b-dropdown-items -->
  </b-dropdown>
</div>
```

```
.dropdown-box {
    border: 2px solid red;
    div, button {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: The sample code didn't work, but I realized what the error was: I am using the css in the Vue scoped style but the css code does not applied to the .dropdown-trigger element. So I changed the scoped style to global and the dropdown get the 100% width.

Comment: They could really implement the expanded="true" attribute, like the button component. And adding this scss:
.is-expanded {
    div, button {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Now, Buefy dropdown already has `expanded` property. You can make `b-dropdown` as fullwidth like this:

```
<b-dropdown expanded>
</b-dropdown>
```

See more props [here](https://buefy.org/documentation/dropdown)